# How to copy files using a txt list to define beginning of file names

Tags: powershell

Hello awesome community :)

I have a list containing a bunch of SKU's. All the filenames of the files, that I need to copy to a new location, starts with the corresponding SKU like so

```
B6BC004-022_10_300_f.jpg
```

In this case "B6BC004" is the SKU and my txt list contains "B6BC004" along with many other SKU's.

Somewhere in the code below I know I have to define that it should search for files beginning with the SKU's from the txt file but I have no idea how to define it.

```
 Get-Content .\photostocopy.txt | Foreach-Object { copy-item -Path $_ -Destination "Z:\Photosdestination\"}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just to confirm, you're wanting to loop through your text file, find the find that corresponds to it and then move that file to another location?

Comment: @I.T Delinquent - Yes exactly except that the lines in the txt file only contains the SKU like: "B6BC004" but the file could be named "B6BC004-022_10_300_f.jpg" or "B6BC004-brkad.jpg" etc. So for each line in the txt a file should be found which name starts with the SKU :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all files start with one of the SKU's, followed by a dash like in your example, this should work:

```
$sourceFolder = 'ENTER THE PATH WHERE THE FILES TO COPY ARE'
$destination  = 'Z:\Photosdestination'

# get an array of all SKU's
$sku = Get-Content .\photostocopy.txt | Select-Object -Unique
# loop through the list of files in the source folder and copy all that have a name beginning with one of the SKU's
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -File -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { $sku -contains ($_.Name -split '\s*-')[0] } | 
    ForEach-Object { $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $destination }
```

Comment: Hello again @Theo - again I much appreciate your help. However when I run the command nothing happens. Should "$rootfolder" on line 7 be replaced with "$sourceFolder"? :) Either way I've tried with both but nothing happens

Comment: @DanielBeck Dos the destination path `Z:\Photosdestination` exist? Does `photostocopy.txt` contain SKU's each on a separate line? (that's what your own code suggests..). P.S. you were right about the `$sourceFolder` variable. That was a mistake..

Comment: Yes, yes and yes. The destination folder and txt file both exist under the correct name and path. The txt file contains SKU's each on a separate line with no commas or symbols. just a txt string on each line. @Theo

Comment: @DanielBeck In that case I fail to see why _nothing happens_. Culd you try adding a `-WhatIf` switch to the Copy-Item cmdlet and report what that outputs? You didn't mention it, but are all the files to be copied **directly** in the source folder or are they inside subfolders of that? If that is the case, add `-Recurse` to the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet.

Comment: I'm sorry, yes the files resides in subfolders as well. I added the recurse and this time when I ran the cmd I could see that it was processing the cmd, ie unlike before, something is happenning now. BUT no photos are coppied to the destination folder. The -WhatIf switch prompts an error message saying "The -WhatIf and -Confirm parameters are not supported for scripts blocks." @Theo

Comment: @DanielBeck Ah, so the WhatIf was a bad idea. Thanks for confirming that with the `-Recurse` switch the problem is solved.

Comment: I got it to work @Theo - It turns out that the split was set to occur at the dash, ie "-". But since the file names had a space before the dash the code found no filenames matching the requirements. Changing the code so that there was a space before the dash made the code work. Like so Where-Object { $sku -contains ($_.Name -split ' -')[0] } |

Comment: @DanielBeck I see, then maybe using `$_.Name -split '\s*-'` would even do better because then the filename could have spaces in front of the dash of not. I have edited the answer just for completeness to use this.

Comment: You're the man @Theo - Thanks a ton for your invaluable help!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this so please proceed with caution!

What is does it loops through all the items in your `photostocopy.txt` file, searches the `$source` location for a file(s) with a name like the current item from your file. It then checks if any were found before outputting something to the console and possibly moving the file(s).

```
$source = '#PATH_TO_SOURCE'
$destination = '#PATH_TO_DESTINATION'
$photosToCopy = Get-Content -Path '#PATH_TO_TXT_FILE'

$photosToCopy | ForEach-Object{

    $filesToCopy = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -File | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "$_*"}

    if ($fileToCopy.Count -le 0){
        Write-Host "No files could be found for: " $_
    }else{
        $filesToCopy | ForEach-Object{
            Write-Host "Moving: " $_.Name
            Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $destination
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know how if this helps you :)